# getting only certain entries of the database

Tags: php

The code bellow gets a few domains from my database and outputs them in a dropdown list. I need some help as I can't get this change i want to make work.

I want to show only the domains where in the database `premium_only` is set to 6, nothing else. If I try to change the `if` statement to `$shortUrlDomain['premium_only'] == 6` I can't see any domains appear in the list which has `premium_only` set to 6 in the database. Why?

Database layout:

```
id | domain      | premium_only | status  | date_created
---+-------------+--------------+---------+-------------------
1  | exaple.com  | 0            | enabled | 2020-03-02 08:13:0
2  | exaple2.com | 6            | enabled | 2021-03-02 08:13:0
```

PHP code:

```
<div>
  <label for="shortUrlDomain"><?php echo t("short_url_domain", "Short Url Domain"); ?>:</label>
  <select id="shortUrlDomain" name="shortUrlDomain" style="width: 100%;">
<?php
foreach ($shortUrlDomains AS $k => $shortUrlDomain) {
  // active domains only
  if ($shortUrlDomain['status'] != 'enabled') {
    continue;
  }
  $lastPremiumOnly = $shortUrlDomain['premium_only'];
  echo '<option value="' . (int)$k . '"';
  // selected option
  if ($k == (int)$_REQUEST['shortUrlDomain']) {
    echo ' SELECTED';
  }
  echo '>';
  '</option>';
}
echo '</optgroup>';
?>
  </select>
</div>


// get base urls
$shortUrlDomains = getShortUrlDomains();


    static function getShortUrlDomain($domainId)
    {
        // get base urls
        $shortUrlDomains = getShortUrlDomains();

        if(!isset($shortUrlDomains[$domainId]))
        {
            return _CONFIG_SITE_PROTOCOL.'://'._CONFIG_SITE_FULL_URL;
        }

        return _CONFIG_SITE_PROTOCOL.'://'.$shortUrlDomains[$domainId]['domain'];
    }
```

Comment: This snippet of code only shows the rendering of the query results, and not the query itself! Could you show us how the `$shortUrlDomains` variable gets set?

Comment: i added it to the post

Comment: That's `getShortUrlDomain($domainId)`... how about `getShortUrlDomains()`, **plural**? (Referenced inside the snippet you added.

Comment: You seem to consider the loop value `$shortUrlDomain` as another `array` (E.g. `$shortUrlDomain[status']`). Is this what you want? Because a database most often does not return a resultset containing multiple dimensions. Consider using `SELECT domain FROM my_table WHERE premium_only = 6;`. And then using `$shortUrlDomains` as an array of resulting ROWS: each `$shortUrlDomain` contains that premium domain value.

Comment: i think i added the correct one to the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, but you might add this statement earlier in your code.

Ideally you'd alter the database query further down the stack, but you question doesn't include any mention of how you set `$shortUrlDomains`.

```
<?php
// somewhere before you render the HTML as in the snippet from your Q.

/**
 * This makes shortUrlDomains into a subset of the original array, 
 * showing only those who have a `premium_only` key with a value of `6`.
 */
$shortUrlDomains = array_filter($shortUrlDomains, function($domain) {
    return (int) $domain['premium_only'] === 6;
});
```

See more of `array_filter` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), at the PHP docs.